# Performing a simple arithmetic operation using SSE (IA32 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

At my university we were just introduced to IA32 SSE. What I am trying to do is to add two vectors (They call it a "packed value", it means that the vector contains four 32-bit single precision floating point numbers. One verctor's size is 128 bit.) Here's what I am trying to do:

```
%xmm0      | 5.5 | 1.2 | 2.4 | 7.0 |
%xmm1      | 3.0 | 1.5 | 3.5 | 2.2 |
              |     |     |     |
              +     +     +     +
              |     |     |     |
              V     V     V     V
%xmm0      | 8.5 | 2.7 | 5.9 | 9.2 |
```

However, on the slides they only show the following code snippet which I simply don't get to work:

```
# %eax and %ebx contain the addresses of the two vectors that are to be added
movups (%eax), %xmm0
movups (%ebx), %xmm1
addps %xmm1, %xmm0
movups %xmm0, result
```

This raises two questions:

**1. How do I even create these vectors in the first place and how do I make %eax and %ebx point to them?**

**2. How do I print the result in order to check whether the operation was successful or not?**

Here's what I tried. The following code compiles and does not crash when I run it. However, there's no output at all... :/

```
.data
    x0: .float 7.0
    x1: .float 2.4
    x2: .float 1.2
    x3: .float 5.5
    y0: .float 2.2
    y1: .float 3.5
    y2: .float 1.5
    y3: .float 3.0
    result: .float 0
    intout: .string "Result: %f.\n"

.text
.global main

main:
    pushl x3
    pushl x2
    pushl x1
    pushl x0
    movl %esp, %eax
    pushl y3
    pushl y2
    pushl y1
    pushl y0
    movl %esp, %ebx

    movups (%eax), %xmm0
    movups (%ebx), %xmm1
    addps %xmm1, %xmm0
    movups %xmm0, result

    pushl result
    pushl $intout
    call printf
    addl $40, %esp
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: `movups %xmm0, result` will write all 128 bits of `xmm0` to `result`, but you've declared `result` as a `float` (32 bits), so it would overwrite parts of the `intout` string.

Comment: Your result should be long enough to contain 4 values, now `movups %xmm0, result` also trashes your string.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! How do I declare `result` in a way that it is 128 bits large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%f` specifier for `printf` indicates a *double* argument, not a float argument. As such, you need to covert the single-floats in your result vector and move them to the stack. This is how I would do that:

```
.section ".rodata"
fmt:    .string "%f %f %f %f\n"
        .align 16
vec1:
        .float 7.0
        .float 2.4
        .float 1.2
        .float 5.5
vec2:
        .float 2.2
        .float 3.5
        .float 1.5
        .float 3.0    

.data
        .align 16
result:
        .float 0.0
        .float 0.0
        .float 0.0
        .float 0.0

        .text
.globl main
main:
        movl    %esp, %ebp

        andl    $-16, %esp      # align stack

        movaps  vec1, %xmm0
        movaps  vec2, %xmm1
        addps   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movaps  %xmm0, result

        subl    $36, %esp
        movl    $fmt, (%esp)
        movss   result, %xmm0
        cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 4(%esp)
        movss   result+4, %xmm0
        cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 12(%esp)
        movss   result+8, %xmm0
        cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 20(%esp)
        movss   result+12, %xmm0
        cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 28(%esp)
        call    printf
        addl    $36, %esp

        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %ebp, %esp
        ret
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! I understand that since `%f` expects double-precision floating-point numbers, we have to perform a conversion. However, isn't there a wildcard out there that expects single-precision? This would make the whole thing a lot easier!

Comment: It would indeed, but there is no such specifier. Note that C will transparently do the conversion, so none of the clumsiness is visible from the level at which `printf` is intended to be used.

Comment: You forgot to save/restore the caller's `%ebp`.  Also, you're defeating the purpose of aligning `%esp` by 16 if you `sub $36` (not a multiple of 16), misaligning it for the `call` instruction.  (Modern versions of the i386 System V ABI require 16-byte stack alignment before function calls.)  But yes, otherwise good example of using SSE2 to store stack args for `%f`.  (For more details about `%f` taking a double, and how C works, see [How to print a single-precision float with printf](//stackoverflow.com/q/37082784))

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about how to declare a label on multiple data items, and how to load a label into a register.  A label is just an address -- a point in memory -- without any size or anything else associated with it.  Things after the label are in consecutive addresses in memory.  So you declare a label referring to a vector as:

```
x:
    .float 7.0
    .float 2.4
    .float 1.2
    .float 5.5
```

Now you can load that address into a register with a simple move, then use the register to load the vector:

```
    movl   $x, %eax
    movups (%eax), %xmm0
```

Alternately, you can load directly from the label

```
    movups x, %xmm0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Chris! However, I have two questions left: Doesn't it have to be `leal x, %eax`? We want `%eax` to hold the address of x, not the value that is to be found there, right? And secondly, how can I print my results to make sure it has worked?

Comment: @baerenfaenger:  Yes, you need a `$` to get the value of the label as an immediate (rather than loading from the label), which I originally mistyped (important typo).  Or you can use `leal`.